# Swapping elements of list

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Say I have a directed graph inputted in the following format in *Mathematica*:

```
g = {{1, "a", 2}, {2, "b", 1}}
```

I'd like to plot this graph using `GraphPlot` in *Mathematica*, which is the following syntax:

```
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {2 -> 1, "b"}}, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True, 
    VertexCoordinateRules -> Auto, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

How would I swap the middle elements and the last elements in any list like `g`, so that `g` would look closer to the argument of `GraphPlot`?

```
{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {2 -> 1, "b"}}
```

I have searched the *Mathematica* documentation but was unable to find a good way of doing this.

Comment: All you need is a simple replacement rule: `g /. {f_Integer, m_String, l_Integer} :> {f -> l, m}`

Comment: Thanks! That was really simple and clean.

Comment: Also `g[[All, 1]] = Rule @@@ g[[All, {1, 3}]];g[[All, {1, 2}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rm -rf has suggested the simplest solution which matches the elements and swaps them around:

```
g = {{1, "a", 2}, {2, "b", 1}};
g /. {a_Integer, b_String, c_Integer} :> {a -> c, b}
{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {2 -> 1, "b"}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this your intention:

```
Graph[Labeled[#1 \[DirectedEdge] #3, Style[#2, 20]] & @@@ g]
```

[image]

or with more formatting:

```
Graph[Labeled[#1 \[DirectedEdge] #3, Style[#2, 20]] & @@@ g, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> 0.2, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this-- yes, this also works, but alas I can only accept one answer.