# Swap two elements in a list in a recursive manner

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a function which takes a list as an argument, and I have to swap two precise elements of the list. My call is of the form

```
f[h1_,{n1___}] :=
```

I need that under a certain test which will be an a If statement, two precise elements of `n1` are switched. 
I may therefore need a `Module` to store the intermediate list and call my function `f` with the new list. I checked [Swapping elements of list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34914/swapping-elements-of-list) and [Swap elements in list without copy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54665/swap-elements-in-list-without-copy) but in both those questions, the proposed function never return the desired list but just modify the actual list.

```
f[h1_,{n1___}] = If[test=True,f[h1,{swappedN1}],ElseStatement]
```

I therefore need a function that makes

```
swap[{1,2,3,4},1,2] -> {2,1,3,4}
```

such that I can do something like

```
 f[h1_,{n1___}] = If[test=True,f[h1,swap[{n1},pos1,pos2],ElseStatement]
```

Is that possible in Mathematica ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a temporary variable:

```
swap[a_List, p_, q_] := Module[{aa = a}, aa[[{p, q}]] = aa[[{q, p}]]; aa]

swap[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 1, 2]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 3, 4}
> ```

Actually I just remembered there *is* a built-in for this: [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) with [`Cycles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cycles.html)

```
Permute[{1, 2, 3, 4}, Cycles[{{1, 2}}]]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 3, 4}
> ```

Also [`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) is rather clean:

```
swap[a_, p_Integer, q_Integer] := ReplacePart[a, {p -> a[[q]], q -> a[[p]]}]
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

```
list = Range[4];

SubsetMap[RotateRight, list, {1, 2}]
```

{2, 1, 3, 4}

```
SubsetMap[RotateRight, list, {2, 4}]
```

{1, 4, 3, 2}

```
swap[a_, b_, c_] := SubsetMap[RotateRight, a, {b, c}]

swap[list, 1, 2]
```

{2, 1, 3, 4}

**Addendum** (not part of the question, but good to know)

We can also employ `swap` to change matrix rows or columns:

```
list = ArrayReshape[Range[12], {3, 4}];

list // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Swap **rows** 1 and 2

```
swap[list, 1, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Swap **columns** 2 and 3

```
Query[All, swap[#, 2, 3] &] @ list
```

or, alternatively,

```
ArrayReduce[swap[#, 2, 3] &, list, 2]
```

give

[image]